# Error "Cannot find module 'errors.server.controller.js'" while trying to extend default backend

Tags: mean-stack, meanjs

I want to add new code to my backend, which will put some data to MongoDB collection. I decided to do it in `core.server.controller.js` because my app will be really simple and I don't need to create a new module for this. So I opened `/app/controllers/users/users.profile.server.controller.js`, a mean.js built-in controller and copied

```
var _ = require('lodash'),
errorHandler = require('../errors.server.controller.js'),
mongoose = require('mongoose'),
passport = require('passport'),
User = mongoose.model('User');
```

to `core.server.controller.js` file to provide mongoose and the other stuff. Then I removed `../` from `errorHandler` `require` argument and changed mongoose model name to my own, which I've created before.

But when I want to start this app in console, I get an error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'errors.server.controller.js'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
at require (module.js:384:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/developer2/baca/app/controllers/core.server.controller.js:7:17)
at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
at require (module.js:384:17)
at module.exports (/Users/developer2/baca/app/routes/core.server.routes.js:5:13)
at /Users/developer2/baca/config/express.js:118:35
at Array.forEach (native)
at module.exports (/Users/developer2/baca/config/express.js:117:49)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/developer2/baca/server.js:24:38)
```

So how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You are requiring `errors.server.controller.js` however the path is wrong.

You can either use the file path relative to your app root directory or to the file (`core.server.controller.js`) from where you're requiring:

**Solution 1: Path relative to the app root directory (preferred for the sake of consistency since MEAN.js uses `path` for requires in other js files):**

You can use node `path` module to help you with this like so:

```
var path = require('path),
    errorHandler = require(path.resolve('./modules/core/server/controllers/errors.server.controller.js'));
```

Note that the file path is relative to the root directory of your app and `path` module will handle that for you.

**Solution 2: Path relative to the current file:**

Since they are both in the same directory:

```
var errorHandler = require('./errors.server.controller.js');
```